# String Compare not working in C

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have a function in my program that is supposed to take Morse code input, compare it to an array of strings and return a letter from a corresponding string once it has found the matching Morse. I've finally managed to get it to run without crashing, but now it keeps returning the wrong letters. For instance ... --- ... should return sos but instead I get amb. I tried testing it by printing out the index number, the morse code string and the letter and it all matched up, so I think the problem is with string compare.

Here's the code:

```
void morsetotext(char mor[])
{
     char alpha[]={"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "};
     char *morse[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", 
     "..", ".---","-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", 
     "...", "-", "..-", "...-",".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.","-----", ".----", 
     "..---", "...--", "....-",".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----." "/ "};
     char letter[8];
     char convert[250];
     int con_count=0;
     int let_count=0;
     int count=0;
     int index=0;
     int length=strlen(mor);

     while (count<length)
     {
           for(let_count=0; let_count<8 && mor[count]!=' '; let_count++)
           {
                            letter[let_count]=mor[count];
                            count++;
           }

           letter[let_count+1]='\0';

           index=0;
           while (strcmp (letter, morse[index])!=1)
           {
                 index++;
           }

           count++;

           printf ("%c", alpha[index]);
     } 
     return;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Sorry about that, here's the whole function.

Comment: Show us the declaration and definition of `letter`. Sounds like it may be a `char`, in which case your call to `strcmp` is wrong.  Do you have your warning level turned up?  Are you ignoring any warnings?

Comment: Yes, the problem is clearly with string compare... a function that hundreds of thousand of programmers have used millions of times without a problem.  Read "The first rule of programming":  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html

Comment: I meant that I thought I might be using it wrong. I'm still learning, and I was hoping for more experienced eyes to help me find the problem. Thank you though, for your polite response.

Answer (score 5):

```
while (strcmp (letter, morse[index])!=1)
```

You probably meant `0` instead of `1`. Or just say `while (!strcmp(...))`.

Answer (score 5):

Compare strcmp() against 0, not 1. the function will only return 0 with a full match. Read the manual! :)

Comment: If you mean change it to while (strcmp (letter, morse[index]) !=0), I've tried that, repeatedly, and it crashes the program.

Comment: @user1827962: A valid comparison will never crash a program, so either `letter` is the wrong type or your incrementing `count` past the end of `morse` or `alpha`.  Please answer the question I asked in the comment.  Either way, comparing against 1 is wrong, and I can guarantee you that `strcmp` is not broken.

Comment: The program will also crashes if you feed it a morse code it can't recognize because 'index' will run beyond the end of the morse[] array.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
letter[let_count+1]='\0';
```

is writing to `letter[9]` if the input (`mor`) is 8 characters long.

You declared letter as `char letter[8];`, so the only valid indicies are [0] - [7].

Assigning to `letter[9]` is most likely causing the seg-fault you describe.

It seems to me that you want letter to contain up to 8 data characters, plus one null-terminator  (`\0`).   That suggests you should declare it as `char letter[9];`.

Comment: This was the source of the seg-fault. Thank you for pointing it out.